# Cannot read property of some JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am writing a simple script that will display Major League Baseball scores via the MLB API. I'm pulling in the master scoreboard json file and accessing some of the values. It was all working great until I started accessing the actual scores of the games which are nested objects in the JSON file.

Here is what I have:

```
var mlb = 'http://mlb.mlb.com/gdcross/components/game/mlb/year_2016/month_04/day_07/master_scoreboard.json';

i = 0;

$.ajax({
  url: mlb,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){

    var games = data.data.games.game;

    $.each(games, function() {
      var home  = games[i].home_team_name,
          away  = games[i].away_team_name,
          venue = games[i].venue,
          homeScore = games[i].linescore.r.home,
          awayScore = games[i].linescore.r.away;

         $('<p>' + home + ' vs ' + away + ' - ' + venue + '</p>').appendTo('#scoreboard');
         $('<p>' + homeScore + ' - ' + awayScore + '</p>').appendTo('#scoreboard');
         i++;
      });
     }
    });

    // why is the dbacks (game 7) game not showing when linescores are displayed?
```

If I simply comment out the `homeScore` and `awayScore` variables the missing games (such as the Dbacks vs Cubs game) reappear.

I am getting an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'r' of undefined`

But when I use a JSON viewer the object `linescore.r` looks the same as any other game and if I change the `i` variable to `7` (the id for the dbacks game) and remove the `i++` it shows the correct values for the dbacks game.

You can find a link to the codepen here: http://codepen.io/erwstout/pen/wGppOV

Thanks!

Comment: The codepen works fine for me.

Comment: @Juhana thats my fault, i changed the date on the API pull and then pen auto saved. Try again if you could. I changed it back to todays date and the dbacks game should be missing. That also makes me wonder if there is an issue with today's JSON feed since yesterdays throws no errors at all....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Indians vs Red Sox - Progressive Field** doesn't seem to have a linescore value. Check for it first. Also you can use the iterator and value parameters in the callback instead of incrementing `i`.

Nice feed.

```js
var mlb = 'http://mlb.mlb.com/gdcross/components/game/mlb/year_2016/month_04/day_07/master_scoreboard.json';
$.ajax({
    url: mlb,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){

        var games = data.data.games.game;

        $.each(games, function(i,v) {
            var home  = v.home_team_name,
                away  = v.away_team_name,
                venue = v.venue,
                homeScore, 
                awayScore;
            if(v.linescore){
                homeScore = v.linescore.r.home,
                awayScore = v.linescore.r.away;         
            } else {
                homeScore = "n/a",
                awayScore = "n/a";          
            }
            $('<p>' + home + ' vs ' + away + ' - ' + venue + '</p>').appendTo('#scoreboard');
            $('<p>' + homeScore + ' - ' + awayScore + '</p>').appendTo('#scoreboard');
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=scoreboard></div>
```

Comment: thanks so much! I didn't notice that game was postponed today so therefor would possibly throw an error. This is my first jump into looping through JSON Objects, I assume `i` is `index` and `v` is value? Would you happen to know where I could find a  little bit of documentation I could read up on to further my learning? Thanks for the nudge in the absolute right direction!

Comment: Yes, Im pretty consistent about using `v` and `i`. jQuery is funny because it uses those in a non-conventional order. Array.forEach is the opposite. I remember by thinking 'jQuery is so sick it needs an IV' :)  I'll have to get back to you on reading that would help out.

Comment: Have you considered using templates? It's a really clean way to do it.  I don't normally use canJs, but I grabbed it to make a quick client side sample. You can also use nodeJs templating with something like express or marko. http://jsbin.com/hugepe/7/edit?css,output There's a lot of documentation out there for these.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing knowledge. I'm very early in this thought process so templates and what not was next on the list. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. It was actually fun, I learned some canJs last night. Oh, one more thing. I noticed when linescore is only one object it isn't wrapped in an array anymore, which is strange but i've seen that before in data feeds. I haven't checked, but I'm assuming that's what caused the problem. You have to handle that case separately. Check the jsbin link (http://jsbin.com/hugepe/7/edit?html,js,output) and you'll see the if/else-if in the HTML template. The ones with a `.length` property are Arrays and the ones with a `.first` property are Objects. The rest I assume are empty.

Answer (score -1):

It seems some data does not contain linescore. You need to check the property before use it.

```
 homeScore = games[i].linescore ?jQuery.parseJSON(games[i].linescore.r.home): {},
 awayScore = games[i].linescore ?jQuery.parseJSON(games[i].linescore.r.away) : {};
```

Comment: thats true. And you can use  `$.each(games, function(i, val) {` instead of implementing `i` variable by `i++`

Comment: Linescore is absolutely in all of the games, I can see it in the JSON Viewer tool. Which is why It's so frustrating.Using your suggesting also breaks the script all together. EDIT: You're right about linescore. I didn't notice the indians game was postponed therefor no linescore. Thanks!

Comment: I think JSON Viewer already cover this issue for you. Actually, you could console.log(games[i]) to log this object in Chrome console. You cannot find your required linescore in some loops.